# How to convert data into this form in SQL :

Tags: sql, arrays, presto, recursive-query, unnest

Input:

[image: Input]

I have to Convert data from input to output. where we trying if for id freq is n then create n rows of that id.

Output:

[image: output]

Comment: Presto <> MySQL. I removed these conflicting tags, please retag only the one database that you running.

Comment: I can't see anything in your images, just empty boxes. Anyway, please, please don't post code and data as (link to) images, but as formatted text instead

Comment: now it's working. please check

Comment: "then create n columns" - do you mean rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Presto, one option uses [`sequence()`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#sequence) and a lateral join to generate the rows:

```
select t.id, x.value
from mytable t
cross join lateral unnest(sequence(1, t.freq)) as x(value)
order by t.id, x.value
```

Comment: If you could provide some sort of _DB fiddle_ that would be awesome.

Comment: @Abra: unfortunately, there is no Presto fiddle that I know about...

Comment: @Abra, GMB re fiddle -- see https://twitter.com/findepi/status/1281329811026305030. I am happy to help with Presto side if there is interest.

Answer (score 1):

Great question - one approach is to use a table of integers - if you are certain there will never be more than (say) 128 repeats you can create the table of integers as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE nums(i INT PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT INTO nums VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO nums SELECT 1+i FROM nums;
INSERT INTO nums SELECT 2+i FROM nums;
INSERT INTO nums SELECT 4+i FROM nums;
INSERT INTO nums SELECT 8+i FROM nums;
INSERT INTO nums SELECT 16+i FROM nums;
INSERT INTO nums SELECT 32+i FROM nums;
INSERT INTO nums SELECT 64+i FROM nums;
```

Now you can use that table:

```
SELECT id, i AS value
 FROM input JOIN nums ON i BETWEEN 1 AND Freq
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do that with Lateral as GMB showed. In SQL server however it could be done in another way like below as an example:

```
with tally as 
(
  select top(select max(v) from myTable)
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t1.Object_ID) AS N
            FROM Master.sys.All_Columns t1
            CROSS JOIN Master.sys.All_Columns t2
)
select m.id, t.N
from tally t
cross join myTable m 
where t.N <= m.v
order by m.id, t.N;
```

[DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=db15c0960dbeb2192030bae4a423f522)